# Get the value of dynamically added text box from table inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Below are the controls in aspx.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="panel" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="holder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bt" Text="Add" onclick="AddTxt" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn1" Text="Refresh" onclick="btn1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
```

When the button Add is clicked i am creating a dynamic table. Below is the C# code

```
protected void AddTxt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tblRows = 3;
    int tblCols = 3;

    Table tbl = new Table();

    for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.ID = "txt" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
            //txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
            tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);

            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

            if (Session["ctls"] != null)
            {
                Session["ctls"] += ";t";
            }
            else
            {
                Session["ctls"] = "t";
            }
        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    holder.Controls.Add(tbl);

    panel.Update();

}
```

When the partial postback occurs on click of Refresh button i am not able to get the value which is updated by user inside the text box. The controls will have empty text.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in holder.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {

        }

    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    if (Session["ctls"] != null)
    {
        string[] ctls = Session["ctls"].ToString().Split(';');
        foreach (string ctlType in ctls)
        {
            if (string.Compare(ctlType, "t") == 0)
            {
                holder.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could any one please help/give me a hint how to work around dynamic controls inside update panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you dynamically create the controls (table, rows, cells, textbox) in the `AddTxt` method you are assigning an `ID` value to the textbox, however when you dynamically create the controls in the `OnInit` event, then you are not creating `ID` value at all, thus the `ViewState` cannot be wired up to what the user typed in and thus lost.

If you create the textbox with the same `ID` value (`txtBox.ID = "txt" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();`) as in the other dynamic control creation logic, then your `ViewState` value would be preserved and properly applied to the textbox upon it being recreated in `OnInit`.

Note: `ViewState` is heavily dependent upon the `ID` values of server controls in order to properly associate values of controls between full and partial postbacks.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. You mean i have to create the same table with same control again on init() ?

Comment: @Naveen - yes that is correct. A not always convenient reality of server controls and ViewState. This is what makes people start to dislike the ASP.NET WebForms model, especially as you start to inject more and more AJAX functionality into your code. The ASP.NET Page life cycle and AJAX tend to butt heads a lot. :-(

Comment: @ Karl Anderson When i call the same method which creates the table AddTxt(), it gives me error!! "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Multiple controls with the same ID 'txt00' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs."

Comment: Oops Sorry, my bad. I was adding to session on each text box creation, I had to create a session for table. Its works good fine now. Thanks Karl for your valuable comment. You saved me a day.

Comment: @Naveen - Great, glad it is working for you. If you feel this answer helped you then please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the corrected code, which works good now. I am adding this here because, it might help some one.

```
 protected void AddTxt(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    add();

}
private void add()
{
    int tblRows = 3;
    int tblCols = 3;

    Table tbl = new Table();

    for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.ID = "txt" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
            //txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
            tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);

            tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        }

        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    holder.Controls.Add(tbl);

    if (Session["ctls"] != null)
    {
        Session["ctls"] += ";t";
    }
    else
    {
        Session["ctls"] = "t";
    }

    panel.Update();
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    if (Session["ctls"] != null)
    {
        string[] ctls = Session["ctls"].ToString().Split(';');


        foreach (string ctlType in ctls)
        {

            if (string.Compare(ctlType, "t") == 0)
            {
                add();
            }
        }
    }
}
```