# C# How to fix run data show in RichTextBox by instand

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a problem about showing data in `RichTextBox` by selected tab, but I don't need to show in the selected tab, I need show by `RichTextBox` for run.

```
    private void btn_Runserver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       AddTab();
       StartCMD();

    }

    private void AddTab()
    {
        TabPage newTab = new TabPage((string)cbConfig.SelectedItem);

        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        rtb.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
        rtb.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        rtb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        rtb.ReadOnly = true;

        newTab.Tag = rtb;
        newTab.Name = (string)cbConfig.SelectedItem;
        newTab.Controls.Add(rtb);

        tabControl.Controls.Add(newTab);
        tabControl.SelectTab(newTab);
    }

    private void build_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string strMessage = e.Data;
        if (tabControl.InvokeRequired)
        {
            tabControl.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)tabControl.SelectedTab.Tag;
                rtb.AppendText(strMessage + Environment.NewLine);
                rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length - 1, 0);
                rtb.ScrollToCaret();
            }));
        }
    }
```

Code RunCMD Form

```
        proc.OutputDataReceived += build_ErrorDataReceived;
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Now my problem is that if I run the program and data show in RichTextbox by selected tab, but I need to show data in `RichTextbox` On `RichText` Tab Safe

Someone said "change `RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)tabControl.SelectedTab.Tag;`, don't use `SelectedTab`", but I not know how to change it accordingly.

Comment: How many `richtextboxes` do you have? Where do you place/store/hold them? it's important to **get access to a specific one** and `AppendText` accordingly.

Comment: Many a lot tab run by button click

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are adding RichTextBox in one event and adding the text to it in another event. So there is a post back while adding the text. In this case, you need to re-add the controls which are dynamically created. Refer [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848791/get-the-value-of-dynamically-added-text-box-from-table-inside-update-panel) which explains how to handle dynamic controls in asp.net.